# Do I have to assign a boolean function to a variable for it to work?

Tags: php

I have a function that registers a user, and it returns the value of the final `execute` statement:

```
function register() {
    //... code ...
    return ($stmt->execute);
}
```

In some places I want to verify that the registration was successful so I check:

```
if (register()) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

but sometimes I don't need to do this check, so will simply calling the function without assigning it work:

```
register();
```

Or, since it returns true/false, I must at least assign it to a variable:

```
$isRegistrationSuccessful = register();
```

Comment: No, storing the return value of any function/method call is absolutely optional. The function call in itself is a valid _statement_, so it doesn’t need anything else for syntactical correctness.

Comment: `but sometimes I don't need to do this check` Why? What's wrong with doing anyway? What if query gave an error?

Comment: Thanks. @vivek_23, you're right, I will probably do this anyway